# Construction of confidence intervals for a Gamma random variable

Tags: statistics, solution-verification, exponential-distribution, confidence-interval, gamma-distribution

**Problem**

Suppose that $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3$ denote a random (independent) sample of size $3$ from a distribution with parameter $\lambda$ defined by the following probability density function:

$$\begin{equation}
  f(y)=\begin{cases}
   \lambda y^{\lambda−1} , & \text{$0 < y < 1$, $\lambda>0$}\\
    0, & \text{elsewhere}
  \end{cases}.
\end{equation}$$

The observed values of the sample are $y_1 = 0.1, y_2 = 0.2 \ \mathrm{and} \ y_3 = 0.3.$

$(a)\quad$ Let $W_i = − \ln(Y_i)$. Find the distribution of each $W_i$.

$(b)\quad$ Derive the distribution of $U = 2\lambda(W_1 + W_2 + W_3).$

$(c)\quad$ Using $(b)$, or otherwise, find an exact central $95$% confidence interval for $\lambda$ and evaluate it for the sample.

**My answers**

(a)

$$\begin{aligned}
y_1 & = e^{-w_1} \\
\frac{dy_1}{dw_1} & = -e^{-w_1}
\end{aligned}$$
As $y_1$ is a decreasing function of $w_1$, so by using the transformation method, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
f_{W_1}(w_1) & = f_Y(y_1) \left| \frac{dy_1}{dw_1}\right| \\
& = \lambda e^{-w_1 \lambda} ,\ \mathrm{where} \ 0 < e^{-w_1} < 1 
\end{aligned}$$

and $$W_1 \sim exp(\lambda), \lambda > 0.$$ By symmetry, it follows that $$W_i \sim exp(\lambda), \lambda > 0.$$

(b)

Let $$J = \sum_{i=1}^{3} W_i.$$ Since $$W_i \overset{iid}{\sim} Exp (\lambda),$$ so
$$\begin{aligned}
J & \sim Gamma \left( 3, \frac{1}{\lambda} \right)\\
\implies U & = 2 \lambda J\\
\implies U & \sim Gamma(3,2)
\end{aligned}$$

As I have just covered these topics, I am uncertain of my calculations and approaches for  $(a)$ and $(b)$. Am I on the right track? If I am, then how should I continue for $(c)$ as it seems my answer to $(b)$ does not contain $\lambda$ anymore? Any intuitive explanations will be highly appreciated!

**Edit**

Following the comments, I have tried the following but am unsure whether it is correct.

$(c)$

$U = 2 \lambda J \sim Gamma (3,2)$

$$0.95 = \mathbb{P} \left( \frac{0.025}{2J} \leq \lambda \leq \frac{0.975}{2J} \right)$$

Thus, it follows that exact central $95 %$ confidence interval for $\lambda$ is $$\left[\frac{0.025}{2(W_1 + W_2 + W_3)} ,\frac{0.975}{2(W_1 + W_2 + W_3)} \right]$$ and the exact central $95%$ confidence interval for $\lambda$ for the sample is $$\left[\frac{0.025}{-2 \ln (0.006)} ,\frac{0.975}{-2 \ln(0.006)} \right].$$

Comment: Look up the concept of pivotal quantity and how you can construct confidence sets from those.

Comment: @Snoop but would you say my answers to $(a)$ and $(b)$ are correct?

Comment: They look alright to me

Comment: Since you say that $\lambda < 0$, isn't the pdf $f(y) = \lambda y^{\lambda-1} < 0$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate that would be peculiar; OP most likely meant $\lambda >0$

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thank you for the spot! $\lambda$ is indeed supposed to be positive. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @Snoop Thank you for the spot! $\lambda$ is indeed supposed to be positive. I have edited the question accordingly. Separately, I have also tried something for $(c)$ but am not sure whether it is correct. Could you check it for me?